# Configure Azure Build Pipeline to run .net core automated integration tests with database

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automated-tests, integration-testing, azure-pipelines

We have already configure Azure Build Pipeline for the project and need to configure continuous automated unit & integration(with database)  tests .

**Project specification**

Build-in .NET Core
Unit and integration tests.
To run the Integration tests a database is required. Database project (SSDT) is part of repository to use .dacpack for deployment.

**What we are trying to achieve**

We are expecting a report should be generated on each build with the following data:

Total Unit tests with pass/fail status.
Total integration tests with pass/fail status.

Since we are using Azure Build Service where we are able to run the Unit tests successfully but not able to run Integration tests because we need a database for the same.

- Reseed of integration database required for each build
- Need the approach to update the database if any schema changes happens in repository database project.

Comment: Can you clarify what's the question here? Why aren't you using a test database where you can pass the credentials through the build pipelines?

Comment: Question is how database schema changes will get applied & how to reseed the database on every build?

Comment: I have written a blog post how to test migration on production data by making a copy to a new temporary database. Maybe this will get you some hints how to get started: https://devblog.pekspro.com/posts/test-migrations-on-production-data

Comment: @PEK this is very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Service Containers

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Add one to your build pipeline and use the SQL base image of your choice.

Build your SSDT project

Create a new DB on the container hosted SQL server

Deploy the Dacpac to the container hosted SQL server

Run your integration tests

Comment: update, ran into problems with these talking to each other and now do docker commands in the build pipeline instead